# Gray level co-occurrence matrix method on C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, glcm

Where can I find an implementation Level Cooccurrence Matrix (GLCM) method for the extraction of feature values from color textures on C#? (with source code of course). And need calculation parameters: average or mean value, standard deviation, contrast, dissimilarity, homogeneity and energy.

Comment: *push. I am looking for the same...

Answer (score 0):

Accord framework (http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/N_Accord_Imaging.htm) provides methods for calculating GLCM matrix and Haralick descriptors. However it lacks dissimilarity parameter.